# Javascript setting the value but not read on server side (the first time!)

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, onclick

I'm setting an hidden input value with few lines of javascript, and then I'm submitting the form. The value seems to be set correctly but it's not read by the controller.

If I try a refresh, the value is read...

This is the code (very straightforward, and I'm using the same code in a different jsp):

```
<form:input path="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="0" />
```

this is how I call the function in the `<td>`

```
onclick="return setId('${us.id}');"
```

and this is the function:

```
function setId(id) {
    document.getElementById('id').value = id;
    document.forms["myForm"].submit();
    return true;
}
```

With Chrome I can see that the value is set, so I cannot understand why it's not received immediately by the server and I need to refresh. I've also tried to remove the return, create one more function to call or other strange stuff..

I'm using Java with Spring.

---

**EDIT:**

Clicking the button I'm changing controller, could be a problem?

I'm doing a research with controller1, then I'm selecting the user to modify clicking on it and redirecting to the controller2 for the modification.

---

**EDIT2:**

The problem seems to be Spring. I've tried to get the value from the request and seems to be there. For now I'm bypassing it this way.

`request.getParameter("id")`

Any suggestions on this behaviour?

Comment: Can you say how do you check this value on server side?

Comment: It's loaded by spring in a bean. I'm using an AbstractWizardFormController.